# In what order should I perform these renovation tasks?

Tags: painting, renovation, new-home

I've just bought a new house and I want to do a couple of improvements, I'm just not sure in what order should they be done. I'm kind of new to this stuff.

What I plan to do:

1. Painting the walls only (*Plan to do this myself*)
2. Installing    New blinds
3. Changing the carpets in the rooms
4. Professional Cleaning
5. Installing some down lights

I plan to use roller blinds.

Comment: #5, #3, #4, #1, #2.  Do the dirty work first and the finish work last

Comment: Professional cleaning after carpet pull-up but before new carpet...  because animal urine is *that* nasty.

Answer (score 5):

I'd paint the ceiling, unless it's like new it will look out of place with fresh walls and floors.

> Installing some down lights

I'd do this first because of gravity - dirt falls down - you don't want that on brand new carpets, even the walls might get dirty so do it before the paint.  No big deal painting around recessed lighting.

> Painting 
>   Changing the carpets in the rooms

Paint, then carpet - obvious reasons.  It's great if you can paint on carpets that are getting torn out.  Carpet is better than dropcloths because it soaks up any paint you get on the soles of your shoes.

> Installing New blinds

I'd do this last, in fact I'd wait until the paint and carpets are in to pick out your blinds.  It makes minimal mess.  You don't want to paint around them.

> Professional Cleaning

Always clean up last, but once you paint and recarpet, what are they even going to clean?

Comment: Really depends on the blinds though. If they're heavy motorized blinds, for example, you may need a few dirty steps, like anchoring to studs. Personally, I'd make sure whatever anchors are needed for the blinds are installed before painting, then after painting, install the blinds to their hooks/anchors.

Comment: @Jeffrey Im thinking of using roller blinds, I've updated my question

Comment: based on comments would it be better to do cleaning in the beginning or after removing the carpets ?